# Operational error when inserting list of lists into sqlite table with executemany

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a database and inserting a list of lists that are created from an excel sheet.  The main list is created using openpyxl, that list is then split every 18 items into a list of lists.  I would like to then insert all the items into the database.  Not very familiar with SQL but after some research, I managed to put this together:

```
import sqlite3
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
filepath = os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop\\")
data1 = []
data=[]
wb1 = load_workbook(filename=filepath+"exportUL1.XLSX")
ws1 = wb1['Sheet1']                         ###call the worksheet with the data

x = 0 
for row in ws1.iter_rows():
                                        #look for the correct value, "Q" and return all the data in that row to the data list
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'Q':
            data.append(x)              #append the id numbers to the list
            for cell in row:
                data.append(str(cell.value))   #append the row data to the list
    x += 1

data_lists = [data[x:x+18] for x in range(0, len(data),18)]     #convert list to list of lists, split every 18 items

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully";
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE QualityHold(
    Id Int,StorageLocation TEXT, StorageType TEXT, StorageBin TEXT, StorageUnit TEXT,
    Material TEXT, Plant TEXT, Batch TEXT, StockCategory TEXT, SpecialStock TEXT, SpecialStockNumber TEXT,            
    Duration TEXT, PutawayBlock TEXT, StockRemovalBlock TEXT, AvailableStock TEXT, StockforPutaway TEXT,
    PickQuantity TEXT, TotalStock TEXT)''')                                                                   #create the table with these headers

    sql = '''INSERT INTO QualityHold (Id,StorageLocation, 
     StorageType, StorageBin, StorageUnit, Material, 
     Plant, Batch, StockCategory, SpecialStock, 
     SpecialStockNumber, Duration, PutawayBlock, StockRemovalBlock,
     AvailableStock, StockforPutaway, PickQuantity, TotalStock)  
     VALUES 
     (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''#sql command

    cur.executemany(sql,data_lists)###execute the sql command using the list of lists for the variables(LINE 38)

conn.close()
```

Once I run this I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ONP1LDY\eclipse-workspace\WOrk\QualityInspection.py", line 38, in <module>
    cur.executemany(sql,data_lists)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Any help with what would be causing this would be great!

Comment: What is line 38?

Comment: Line 38 is the executemany command

Answer (score 0):

I went a different route and replaced the executemany with the following:

```
for lst in data_lists:
    var_string = ', '.join('?'*len(lst))
    query_string = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO QualityHold VALUES (%s);' % var_string
    cur.execute(query_string, lst)
```